# Sqlplus Copy command not compatibel with rowid data type

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I am facing a problem in using sqlplus copy commmand for copying data from one table in one DB to another DB (both DB don't have DB Link) because of rowid datatype in a column in table.

Table Specifications:
Rowid rid,
Card Char(16)

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Right from the [Oracle manual](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/apb.htm#CHDEAEDE)

```
COPY supports the following datatypes:
  CHAR
  DATE
  LONG
  NUMBER
  VARCHAR2
```

So you cannot copy a table with a `rowid` column.